# How to run rake db:seed in amazon opswork

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, aws-opsworks

I am new to opswork and I dont have much idea about chef recipes. I already set up the application on opswork and it is working fine, now I wanted to load my seed data over there.   Is there any options to run the seed command?

Answer (score 0):

The database seeding needs to be done by you first time around. This is because RoR recipes expect the database to be already there, and run only : rake db:migrate

You need to manually do this.